# Xamarin.Firebase.Auth and LinkedIn - please for advice

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

My project is Xamarin.Forms PCL for Android and iOS.
Current stage is:
I'm able to get LinkedIn authorization(with Xamarin.Auth - OAuth2Authenticator),
and get user info from LinkedIn - Android Project.

What I would like to do:
After authorization, SignIn/LogIn to application using FireBase - in other words integrate OAuth with FireBase?

Is it possible?

I'm not sure if I'm going in good direction, or if I'm thinking right.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an unsupported provider (eg. LinkedIn), you will need to use custom authentication. You would verify the LinkedIn sign in on your server, mint a custom token using Admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens, send the custom token to the client and complete sign in using `signInWithCustomToken`. This is also available via REST API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-verify-custom-token

Comment: Thanks, for answering.
If I understand right, I should:

     1. From Xamarin app(iOS and Android) call ApiController which return 
     LinkedIn Auth Page to mobile app


     2. After filling Login and Password fields, my ApiController should ask 
     LinkedIn  and return token. In ApiController on server side I should use Node.js


     3. I Should pass LinkedIn token to mobile app and use 
     signInWithCustomToken

Is that correct?

Comment: could you take a look please?